# C++ Called object 'int' is not a function or a function pointer

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm new to c++ and I am creating a program to calculate the power of a number using recursion. After writing all the code, I'm getting an error:

Called object 'int' is not a function or a function pointer.

**Here is my full code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int power(int, int);
int main(){

cout << "enter a number " << endl; 

int no, power;

cin >> no;

cout << "enter a power" << endl; 

cin >> power;

cout << "answer is " << power(no, power) << endl; 



return 0;

}

int power(int number,int pow){
if (pow == 1){

return number;
}else {


return number* power(number, pow - 1);

}


}
```

Since I'm new I don't know what this means. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a function called `power` and an `int` called `power`. Try giving your `int` a different name.

Comment: You are obviously confusing the compiler having a variable `power` named the same as your function `power()`. Just don't do that.

Comment: Thanks! Changed the int name, getting no errors now!

Comment: I once had a teacher who told me that I should compiler after each single line. Thats a bit extreme, but at least in this way you never have to search for errors instead of "writing all the code" and then realizing there is an error somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first declare `power` as an integer:

```
int no, power;
```

But then try to call it as a function:

```
power(no, power)
```

They can't both have the same name. Rename either your integer or your function.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you out! ;)

Comment: Yeah, thnx for the help!

Comment: You can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark to indicate that this question has been answered. :)